# How to determine sender for Json SerializerSettings Error

Tags: c#, json

currently in my logs, there's a spike in errors. I have this bit of code that logs an error when a serialization error occurs.  I understand what the error is, but I'm unsure what line of code or what method the error is causing it. Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

in Startup.cs

```
.AddControllersAsServices().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
     options.SerializerSettings.Error = (sender, args) =>
     {
         _logger.LogError($"Failed during serialization: {args.ErrorContext.Path}", args.ErrorContext.Error);
         _logger.LogError($"Error: {args.ErrorContext.Error}");
                    args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                };
     })
```

Here's a sample log

```
2021-06-23 02:19:36.5230|Error|DESKTOP-8DL3QGE|Startup|Thread-5||||||||||||||||||Failed during serialization: |
2021-06-23 02:19:36.9502|Error|DESKTOP-8DL3QGE|Startup|Thread-5||||||||||||||||||Error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "test" to type 'Models.DocumentMetadata'. Path '', line 1, position 6.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to Models.DocumentMetadata.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)|
```

Comment: At first glance it seems like there is invalid data being supplied to one of your controllers when the request is being deserialized into it's respective object where it's expecting a `DocumentMetadata` type but was given a `string` instead - what other avenues have you looked into and/or what type of clarification are you looking for from these logs?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney That's exactly what's happening. But unfortunately DocumentMetadata is used on so many endpoints, I am unable to pinpoint which one it is. I'm stumped from here.

Comment: From the message: `Error converting value "test"`, have you tried searching for "test" in the input string?  perhaps even on "line 1 position 6" ?